# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta de la publicación más comentada en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Quiero hacer un consulta en el gestor de base de datos phpmyadmin, que consulte el artículo más comentado y posicionarlo el primero.

Tengo mas o menos una idea pero, no sabría como hacerlo, que sería consultar un artículo en específico y contar cuantos comentarios tendría, pero eso solo funciona haciendo referencia a un artículo y no a todos en general, eso es lo que no sabría hacer

Comment: Si pones la estructura de las tablas que intervendrían en la consulta podrás tener una o varias respuestas para resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola @Julian, para tener una idea de la consulta primero hay que saber como está estructurada tu base de datos, por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade una imagen o una descripción(bien detallada) de las tablas y sus relaciones

Comment: @Julian, he estado buscando documentación sobre esto ya que hace algún tiempo no trabajo directamente con las consultas, lo que quieres hacer es anidar consultas, googlealo y verás como tienes tu respuesta

Comment: ¿Puede indicar cuáles son tus tablas, que relación hay entre ellas y que resultado esperas para poder ayudarte?

Answer (score 0):

Según he entendido(ya que a tu pregunta le faltan datos) lo que quieres hacer se llama **anidar consultas**, esto es cuando quieres que el resultado de una consulta como campo de una consulta, ya que debes hacer varias cosas:

1. iterar los artículos
2. contar los comentarios
3. retornar el artículo más comentado

Ejemplo: Devuelve todos los productos cuyo precio unitario es mayor que el de cualquier producto vendido con un descuento igual o mayor al 25 por ciento:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   Productos
WHERE
   PrecioUnidad
   ANY
   (
   SELECT
   PrecioUnidad
   FROM
   DetallePedido
   WHERE
   Descuento = 0 .25
)
```

Para otra documentación ver:

[Como anidar una consulta dentro de otra consulta o en una expresión utilizando una subconsulta](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Anidar-una-consulta-dentro-de-otra-consulta-o-una-expresi%C3%B3n-mediante-una-subconsulta-a8532322-e42f-4f94-bc38-ace7c182916a),

[como hacer Subconsultas en SQL](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/2337.php)
entre otros. Lamento no poder darte la consulta completa, pero como ya te dije, tu pregunta está incompleta. Espero que esto te pueda ayudar, Saludos

Comment: Es posible que no necesite un subquery y con un join se pueda resolver, pero falta más información por parte del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

bueno ya que no tienes nada de código en tu pregunta tratare de ayudar con la siguiente consulta para saber el articulo mas comentado suponiendo que tienes un campo en tu tabla articulo que se llame comentario seria lo siguiente

```
select max(count('comentario')) from 'tu tabla'
```

esto te devuelve el el articulo que mas comentario tenga